# REST API best practices: what information do we put in header and what into a body

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

*In general, in REST API services what information we put to a body and what we put to headers?*

For example, I have existing endpoint that updates a user. Like this

```
POST 
{
   "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "some name"
   }
}
```

This endpoint can be called when:

- User updates his data himself
- User calls to customer care and admin changes this information for a user.

I need to add admin user id to tracking if update is done by admin. For this I see two ways.

- I add admin's id to the contract and if it's not empty it means that it's admin who makes changes.

  ```
  POST 
  {
      "user": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "some name"
       },
       "admin_id":""
  }
  ```
- Body remains the same and I add `X-admin-id` to http headers. If it's not empty it means that admin makes this changes.

  ```
  POST 
  {
     "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "some name"
     }
  }
  ```

Is there a best practices or I can use both ways?

Comment: In your specific case, I would expect you to be authenticating and authorizing callers.  Therefore you will know which user is attempting to make the update and whether they have admin privileges.  So that I don't see that you need to add this information to either body or headers.

Comment: The problem is that this service is internal and it does not see what user is authenticated

Comment: If it's internal, it probably doesn't matter much which way you do it, though I would personally avoid using a custom http header.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question and the user may not need an answer. Here is my thought.

We should not have to put the admin_id in the body of the request. So I prefer to follow the second approach. So we just have to check the X-admin-id is available or not. If it's available, then the admin user is doing the operation on behalf of the user otherwise the user itself doing that. I would also prefer to do this check in the Filter class instead of Resource Endpoint.